# Java: KeyLIstener and paintComponent not cooperating

Tags: java, graphics

I have been trying to make a java program that shows a circle on the screen. I have three classes:

1. first ---> initializes the frame and adds the key listener from input.
2. panel ---> contains the paintComponent method and the method that will move the object across the screen(I even remembered to put repaint(); )
3. input ---> implements KeyListener and calls the animation method in panel

In the input class I have this `if` statment:

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
  new panel().animation();
}
```

here is the animation method **inside of the panel class**:

```
public void animation() {
  playerX += 10;
  System.out.println(playerX);
  repaint();
}
```

when I runthe program, I know the animation method is being ran because it is outputing *playerX* to the console (it increased evey time like it was supposed to), but the *repaint();* command is being ignored! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your code for the `paint` method()? `animation()` does nothing but updating a variable...

Comment: I am trying to comprehend why this question was down voted. I did a very thorough explanation of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `KeyListener` is creating a new `panel` every time it receives a `VK_D` event, and invoking `animation()` on that.  That is unlikely to be what you want.  It should probably be invoking `animation()` always on the same `panel` object, that `panel` being a visible component in the application UI.

Comment: so even though I am calling `repaint();` inside of the panel class, it still won't work? If that is the case, would it be better to make a method inside the main class that calls that specific object to repaint?

Don't answer that. I just tested it and it works! Thanks a lot man! Now I can go and make a game of pong!

Comment: `java.awt.Component.repaint()` (and all overrides) is an *instance* method.  You need to invoke it on the instance of your class that is actually contributing to the UI.  I haven't enough information to confidently recommend how best to achieve that, but typically the `KeyListener` instance would hold a reference (in an instance variable) to the `panel` object it is supposed to signal.

Comment: This method of animating things has proven unstable as it is. The program would sleep at a set amount of ticks without regarding the speed of the processor of the computer used to play the games. There is a much better method of creating a game loop I have learned.